# Adding rendered HTML to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, partial-views

Given a controller `MapsController`:

```
class MapsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @campings = Camping.finm(:all) #in reality a much more complex scope.
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @campings }
    end
  end
end
```

This renders the JSON just fine. But now, I'd like to pass along some HTML to inject into the DOM:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "maps.json?bounding=45.446465,-4.935988,53.944621,17.036668",
}).done(function (data) {
  //...
  var gInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:  camping.infowindow
  });
  //...
  $("#campings").append(camping.listing);
});
```

This JavaScript assumes a `.listing` and `.infowindow` attribute in each returned JSON-Object. They should contain HTML,
rendered with the partials `campings/_infowindow.html.haml` and `campings/_listing.html.haml`.

Is this the correct angle to tackle this? Or should I rather build the HTML within the JavaScript and avoid sending HTML? If so, is there still a way to use partials to build the actual HTML?

How can I add `listing` and `infowindow` to the Objects`Camping` model does not have these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a bit rough (and not 100% super the "Rails way") but working fine for me in a similar situation:

```
render :text => {:result => "success",
                 :document_row => render_to_string(
                                  :file => "admin/documents/_document_row",
                                  :formats => "html",
                                  :layout => false,
                                  :locals => {:documentable => documentable})}.to_json
```

so roughly just generating a hash and use render_to_string to get the html from th _document_row template.

Comment: I am not sure how this renders a collection. It appears to me that this would need  to be wrapped in some `.each` or `.map` block, not?

Comment: For a collection you could use :collection instead of :locals (assuming you template is coded in a way to work with this). But yes, you could first create a string and "collect" several results from render_to_string as well.

Comment: I accepted this answer, because it explained the "render_to_string" which turned out to be the key to solving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use something like KnockoutJS or another javascript data-binding or templating tool, you can have a skeleton 'template' in the page to start with, that gets filled in with camping listings when you make the ajax request.

The way it works is that you have your table or list or whatever of camping listings bound to an array of camping objects in your Knockout model. When you make your ajax request, you just update that array with the json that comes back. When that array is updated, the DOM is automatically updated to show the new listing. This lets your ajax request get the data only and not all the HTML markup, which means fewer bytes over the wire, and you can separate the act of fetching new data from updating the DOM based on that data.